# How to cancel the UIView rotate block animations

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, block

(

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
[super viewDidLoad];
label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 50)];
label.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
label.text = @"hello world";
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[self.view addSubview:label];
[label release];
[self startAnimation];

UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 30);
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:btn];
}

- (void)startAnimation
{
 CGAffineTransform transForm = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angel * M_PI/180.0f);
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.1f delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^(void){
    label.transform = transForm;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    NSLog(@"1");
    angel = angel + 5;
    [self startAnimation];
}];
}

 - (void)btnPressed:(id)sender
 {
  //method 1 :[label.layer removeAllAnimations];   not work...
//method 2 : CGAffineTransform transForm = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/180.0f);
//label.transform = transForm;      not work...
}
```

)

I rotate the label,now I want to cancel it, I searched the likely questions in the site,and found about two solutions,I tried,but the two solutions not work..

Comment: You can also rotate back to same angle. Eg: if you rotated +180, then rotate it again back to -180.. :P

Answer (score 1):

The animation does not stop when you use `[label.layer removeAllAnimations]` because you call `[self startAnimation]` regardless of the value of the `finished` variable. This causes the animation to continue even if you canceled it.

You should change your animation completion block to the following:

```
- (void)startAnimation
{
  CGAffineTransform transForm = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angel * M_PI/180.0f);
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1f delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear     animations:^(void){
    label.transform = transForm;
  } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    if (finished) {
      NSLog(@"1");
      angel = angel + 5;
      [self startAnimation];
    }
  }];
}
```

Use `[label.layer removeAllAnimations]` in `btnPressed`

Comment: yes,It worked.Thank you!I printed the "finished" bool value,It's 0 when I press button.I look the param "completion".the docs says like this: "A block object to be executed when the animation sequence ends. This block has no return value and takes a single Boolean argument that indicates whether or not the animations actually finished before the completion handler was called. If the duration of the animation is 0, this block is performed at the beginning of the next run loop cycle. This parameter may be NULL."       I think the removeAllAnimations operation make the animation finished